# How to check the syntax without using a built-in compiler?

Tags: c, syntax

Thanks for those who answered my previous question before.

Now I have hit another problem with my project.

from this code example,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x;

    x = 5;

    printf("the value is %d.", x);
}
```

I have deconstructed and grouped then accordingly into List from headers (#include), main function (void main() {...}), initialization (int x), assignment (x = 5), and printf statement (printf("..."))

the problem is how to check the syntax without using a built-in compiler?

[I know this might be a vague question to ask but this is what I am working on for the past 3 months and this is the only part I'm having trouble with]

Comment: You don't need the whole compiler, just the parser and lexer, and those probably already exist in some form for your code.  Think YACC, LEX, and ANTLR

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without a built-in compiler"? Do you mean you have to write your own code to check the syntax?

Comment: So.. a cut-down clang ?

Comment: @KyleStrand: Yes. The thing is I have been searching for a way to incorporate just the parser and lexer into my project, but haven't found a way to do so.

Comment: @whozCraig more or less like that.

Comment: @Ian271 [TCC.](http://bellard.org/tcc/) Complete C compiler, small, fast and opensource => you can throw away the code generator and use the parser only.

Comment: @H2CO3 can TCC be used int visual studio c# winform applications?

Comment: @Ian271 What do you mean by that? Is that a legal/licensing issue you're asking about? I think it can, it's under a quite permissive license.

Comment: @H2CO3 I was having a hard time trying to use it in other c# winform applications before but thanks for the heads up.